# Indenting and justifying a paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, paragraphs

I would like to force the justification (after a \raggedright command) of a paragraph while also having it indented.

I tried the following commands but this doesn't seem to work (only the first line of the paragraph is indented, and not even at the right distance) :

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
...
\raggedright
\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\leftskip}{22pt}
{\justifying \lipsum[2] \par}

\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}
\lipsum[3]
```

Would anyone know how to do this ?